# What is the return type of the json method of a response?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I see some examples of Angular 2, which convert the response of `http` into JavaScript object like this:

```
http.get("http://....").subscribe(
    response => {
        let result = response.json();
    },
    error => { 
        console.log('cannot get api');
    }
);
```

I also see some examples which state that `json()` method returns a Promise, which requires the function to be enclosed in `then` to obtain the result:

```
response.json().then(result => ({
    ///
});
```

Why does one use `then` and the other does not? What's the return of value of `json` and which should I use?

Comment: Can you use `console.log(response.json())` in both examples to find out?

Comment: Are the examples from the same code? Could it be the other examples are using `fetch` instead of whatever Angular2 uses?

Comment: You should use the first one, i.e. subscribing to the observable and returning the result as json object. It will be best practice if you creating a function of Observable type and not mixing it with the promises.

Comment: @Bergi, this is not an exact duplicate of the question you linked. This question is related to the differences between Angular's `Response` definition and the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

Comment: @Saravana Oh, right, I thought Angular 2 would be using `fetch`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples where you see `response.json()` returning a `Promise` are part of the Fetch API, which is still experimental: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

> **Body.json()**
>
> Takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It
>   returns a promise that resolves with a JSON object.

The other example you see are from Angular's implementation which returns the data directly instead of a `Promise`: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/body.ts#L26